# Upgrading gcc to 8/9 trigger "Error: unsupported instruction `vmovdqu'" while gcc-7 runs fine

Tags: c++, gcc

I compile Apache Arrow (https://arrow.apache.org/) with CMake 3.15 and gcc/g++-7 (7.5.0) and it goes well. However, when I upgrade gcc/g++ to 8(8.4.0) and 9(9.3.0) with the same CMake version, I got the following errors:

```
/tmp/ccrlCxYO.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccrlCxYO.s:5651: Error: unsupported instruction `vmovdqu'
make[2]: *** [src/parquet/CMakeFiles/parquet_objlib.dir/build.make:194: src/parquet/CMakeFiles/parquet_objlib.dir/encoding.cc.o] Error 1
```

The target file (encoding.cc) is a pure C++ file. It uses Intel Intrinsics, but does not contain any assembly code.

This is the first time I see an "Assembler message" error. So I request some help understanding what it means. My question:

1. When would the assembler complain about unsupported instruction? I have seen unsupported instruction at runtime before, but not this "Assembler message". As this happens after upgrading GCC, I guess this is a new feature of the new compiler/assembler?  I cannot find any document, so if anyone can point to me any doc explaining this it would be very appreciated.
2. Adding "-mavx" to `target_compile_options` does not solve the problem. Anyone has a suggestion of solution to the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not mentioned, but did you delete the cmake generated files and have cmake start from scratch?

Comment: Yes I delete the build folder and start CMake from scratch for both GCC8/9 environments.

Comment: How about upgrading binutils?

Comment: The binutills I use with gcc 9 is the latest version shipped with Ubuntu 20.04, version 2.34. It has this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR:** I found the solution is to add "-mavx512bw" to `target_compile_options`

Please continue reading if you want to hear more detail about the root cause, and how I found it.

After googling a bit I found this webpage talking about a bug of GNU AS. https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-binutils@gnu.org/msg30524.html

That webpage reports that AS does not recognize "vmovdqu16", which needs the support of AVX512VL+AVX512BW. However, the assembler reports an error message saying "vmovdqu" is not supported.

This reminds me that I may encounter the same issue. The AS actually receives "vmovdqu8/16/32" but it reports "vmovdqu". This error message is very misleading because "vmovdqu" and "vmovdqu16" need different instruction set supports. The former only need AVX, but the latter need AVX512BW+AVX512VL.

I decided to give it a try and add -mavx512bw to the compile option ( I already have avx512vl before). It actually fixes the problem.

So I think the whole story is: the newer version of GCC uses some new SIMD instruction, which the old GCC did not use.

Hope this helps someone who also run into similar problems.